# How to populate data if zend form is not validated?

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2

module.config contains form, that is injected into controller

```
'passwordForm' => function($sm){
    $form = new \Application\Form\PasswordForm();

    $form->setInputFilter(new \Application\Form\PasswordInputFilter());

    return $form;
},
```

Controller:

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
    $form->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());

    if($form->isValid()){
        //ok
    }
}
return array('form' => $form);
```

However, if the form is not validated, I see empty fields at form view `<?=$this->formRow($this->form->get('passwordOld'));?>`. If I echo its value, I see it displayed: `<?php var_dump($this->form->get('passwordOld')->getValue());?>`

How can I make visible values of not validated form? The key point is that the form is not binded to any object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password form element is intentionally done in such way for security reasons.
You must never (re)populate form with passwords.

Comment: It's amazing, you are right. If I change type to text, I see it. How could I be so blind :)